# 16.04: Cannot update OwnCloud

Tags: 16.04, update-manager, repository, owncloud-client

I have issues with updates for the OwnCloud desktop release:

```
teddy@Yoga-2:~$ sudo apt-get update --allow-unauthenticated
[sudo] password for teddy: 
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:2 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_15.10  InRelease
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [94,5 kB]
Get:4 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_15.10  Release [1023 B]
Get:5 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_15.10  Release.gpg [189 B]
Ign:5 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_15.10  Release.gpg
Hit:6 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_15.10  Packages
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [94,5 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [242 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages [238 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages [130 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages [127 kB]
Fetched 927 kB in 0s (1111 kB/s)                          
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_15.10  Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 977C43A8BA684223
W: The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_15.10  Release' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

This is no the first time I have issues updating Ownclous but this time I cannot resolve this. Can you please help? How do I authenticate explicitly the repo?
P.S. Adding the GPG key as suggested does not resolve the issue. I remember adding it when installing the client.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is now an [Owncloud client repository for 16.04](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_16.04/), so update your `sources.list` (just replace `15.10` with `16.04`) and try again.

And if you have not yet added the GPG key for the repository, do it as indicated on the [Owncloud client download page](https://software.opensuse.org/download/package?project=isv:ownCloud:desktop&package=owncloud-client):

```
wget http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:ownCloud:desktop/Ubuntu_16.04/Release.key
sudo apt-key add - < Release.key
```

Comment: I tried the first part and the resources list for OwnCloud seem to be in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` so and it already had the record for `16.04` but I added the same record in sources.list and this helped downloading almost all upgrades. I also added `15.10` but this made no difference I think. Now the message is:

`The following packages have been kept back:
  libowncloudsync0 owncloud-client owncloud-client-l10n
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.`

I tried adding the CPG key but this did not help. I might try uninstalling the application.

Comment: If you are running `apt-get upgrade`, try `apt-get dist-upgrade` or `apt upgrade`. (You can aldo do a search for "packages have been kept back".)

Comment: `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` actually helped installing the rest of the updates. Thank you for resolving my issue!

Comment: + Note that if you have previously stored a `Release.key` the system will automatically enumerate. I wasn't vigilant, and just copied the steps above -- with no joy. Then I noticed the `Release.key` had been saved as `Release.key.3` -- and adding that tiny tweak to the `apt-key add` line made all the difference (of course!).

Comment: @Dɑvïd Yes, this problem can be avoided by not storing the key on disk and passing it to `apt-key` directly, with `wget [...] -O - | sudo apt-key add -`.

Comment: Owncloud recently moved sources away from Suse and to their own download-servers: https://central.owncloud.org/t/gpg-error-no-pubkey-4abe1ac7557beff9/2825